# Can a subcategory of the category of sets be self-dual?

Tags: category-theory

Given that **Set**, the category of sets, is not self-dual, can a subcategory of **Set** be self-dual? If so, what are some examples?

Answer (score 2):

Sure - consider the one-element category with a unique morphism. More generally, note that *any* small category is (isomorphic to) a subcategory of **Set**, so any small self-dual category gives an example.

Comment: Thank you, Noah!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Could you explain why/how every category embeds into the category of sets?

Comment: @TaishiWalde An embedding is given by the product of all the covariant representables. This amounts to a slight extension of the fact that the Yoneda embedding is faithful.